# Retrieve and tidy up one directory name in a url. e.g. I need example.com/main/this_dir/page.html to output as "This Dir"

Tags: php

I am stuggling to comprehend how to accomplish the following task "

From : `http://www.example.com/main/this_dir/page.html`

I would like an output of : **This Dir**

When using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` i can get this output :

*/main/this_dir/*

I would like to now take that and strip the last string between the two /'s so i end up with

*this_dir*

I would then like to take that string and turn it into

**This Dir**

There is a slight complication with this too because the directory could simply be called /this/ and not /this_dir/, but it is always one or the other and the text does change whereas the words i used were merely an example.

If anyone has any suggestions, input or feedback as to how i could accomplish this task it would be greatly appreciated! I do have a vague idea of how i could strip the last directory name from the request_uri string but i would really like to know if it would even be possible to transform the string in the way that i have described, using PHP.

Comment: If you have the string, use string functions like `strpos` and `substr` to make thing work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to get the "this_dir" part, so then it's simply a case of doing something like this:

```
$directoryName = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
```

### Edit

Slightly more convoluted example that will work for pages such as "/main/this_dir/something.php":

```
$directoryName = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', basename(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')))));
```

This is just stripping anything after the final "/" before passing to `basename` to ensure it'll work as before. Note that this will **NOT** work though for URLs without a trailing "/" such as "/main/this_dir" - in this case it would output "Main".

Comment: Rob, you are a Master :) Thank you so much that would have taken me the entire day to figure out using Google! It works perfectly and was much simpler than i had thought, I would have figured out the basename bit but i did not even know the ucwords existed! THANK YOU!!

Comment: Ah wait, its not so perfect :) if i go to `/main/this_dir/` it translates the way that i want it to. But all my pages are linked like `/main/this_dir/index.php` and this gives an output of "Index.php"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = explode("/", dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$directory = end($path);
```

This should give you the last directory in the path.

Then you can do:

```
$dirParts = explode("_", $directory);
$dirName = implode(" ", array_map("ucfirst", $dirParts));
```

To get the directory name in a user-friendly format.

Edit: In fact, as RobMaster said, it is probably easier to do `ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $directory))`

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer. This seems to be a useable solution and one that does work as intended. However, when compared to the solution by @RobMasters would this approach not be more resource intensive? This will be run on basically every page of my site in order to generate in part the page title so i would like the quickest solution. What i have done, is combined both of your answers to make this one : `$directoryName = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', end(explode("/", dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])))));` And would that not be the least resource intensive approach?

Comment: Yes - I edited my post when I realised that @RobMasters way of printing the user-friendly directory name was better than mine. In terms of resource usage, I seriously would not worry about that for such a tiny statement. You should only worry about that if you are dealing with huge record sets or big loops. Code readability is probably more important in this case.

Comment: Very useful info, thank you so much for your input! If i could have selected two answers i would have :)